# How to save / load this data?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have a few items I need to save, Its all value for a Map. So each time a user can either load an old map or create and save a new one.  But I am unsure how or what process to use to save all the data.

I have

```
TCube array (1..10000)
Row, Column : integers
NumberOfBlocks : integers
```

So when a user clicks save it should save the array data ( I am not sure it matters but not all 10,000 cubes are created) , along with the 3 integers.

Full code of the creation of the TCUBE array and integers.

```
procedure TForm2.createMap(r:integer;c:integer);
var
 i : integer;
 rows,columns,columnssave : integer;
 x,y,z : single;
 player : tmodel3d;

 begin
 columns := r;
 rows := c;
 i:=1;
 x := 0;
 y := 0;
 z := 0;
 NumberOfRows := rows;
 NumberOfColumns := columns;
 camera1.Position.X := rows/2;
 camera1.Position.Y := columns/2;
 dummy1.Position.X := rows/2;
 dummy1.Position.Y := columns/2;
   while rows>0 do
    begin
      columnssave := columns ;
      while columns >0 do
        begin
           CreateCube[i]:=tcube.Create(self);
           CreateCube[i].Visible := true;
           CreateCube[i].Position.x := x;
           CreateCube[i].Position.Y := y;
           CreateCube[i].Position.Z := z;
           CreateCube[i].Material.Texture.CreateFromFile(gamedir+'\pics\Grass.bmp');
           CreateCube[i].Material.Modulation := TTextureMode.tmReplace;
           CreateCube[i].Parent := viewport3d1;
           CreateCube[i].OnClick := cubeClick;
           CreateCube[i].OnMouseDown := mousedown;
           y:= y+1;
           i:=i+1;
           //z:=z-1;
           columns := columns -1;
        end;
      y:=0;
      x:= x+1;
      z:=0;
      columns := columnssave;
      rows:= rows-1;
    end;
    totalblocks := i;

 setblocks := false;
 label2.Text := inttostr(totalblocks);


 end;
```

Thanks
Glen

Comment: Could you show real code?

Comment: @MBo  currently i have no code to save or load, only create new... as i am not sure how to do save / load  but added the code to show how i create the array

Comment: How do you want the info stored? What type of file? What are the requirements?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would like for it to be stored in a file type that would not let a user open it (like .ini file) and be read.  but as of now i dont care on the type. or how its stored .. only requirements is 1. i can save the data, and 2. i can pull the correct data when loaded.   I have never done anything like this at most i saved some config data into .ini So any help or read is more then welcome.

Comment: Why does that information only appear in a comment?

Comment: well up top it says "But I am unsure how or what process to use to save all the data."  Thus it kind of sounds like i am repeating my self?  Ill be more then happy to add it if that info makes things more clear.

Comment: What would you say if someone answers suggesting that you save to an INI file, or in JSON? You'll say, "I don't want a human readable text file". And then the answerer will have wasted their time. So yes, if you have requirements, they must appear in the Q.

Comment: Are you looking for [TStream.WriteComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TStream.WriteComponent) and [TStream.ReadComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TStream.ReadComponent)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that would be fine, but i would need to still know the how part?  as why i did not put in up there, cause if only answer i can get is .ini file then ok, I did not and do not want to rule it out. but yes preference is a non readable text file.

Comment: @SirRufo Those sound like they would / could work, but how to assign it once to the tcube array and then once for each integer?

Comment: Read from stream until the end and increase a counter for each readed component

Comment: But to get rid of this counter, you can also use an array wrapper called TList/TList<TCube> ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo Is this something you can give an example of as an answer? As i seem to understand better with a small example.

Comment: @GlenMorse -- What is the exact data structure that you are trying to save?  That's what is really needed in order to know how to save it.

Comment: @NickHodges   The position, x,y,z of each TCube then the 3 integers value,  thus if was saved like so  integer,integer,integer,x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z ect..till end of cube array then i could easy write code to read that in and assign new TCubes for these x,y,z.. But issue is what if TCube[55] has not been created but TCube[56] has been, what will the x,y,z values be of 55? and / or how to know to skip it?

Comment: if your going to give a neg or close at least put a comment, I cant read minds and will not ever be able to make the improvement your giving the -1 too if you dont say something.

Comment: -1 because you keep **ignoring all the comments** asking you to provide more details **in your question**. If you can't even provide information about the data structure you're trying to save, it's impossible to give you an answer about how to save it. Additional details need to be in the **question**, not buried in a clutter of comments. You have the ability to [edit] your post to improve or clarify things, but you keep ignoring requests for you to do so. If you want the "-1s" to be removed, you need to improve your question.

Comment: @kenWhite Good,  cause clearly i put "i need to save all the data",  and gave all the data types i neeeded.. And clearly its says i am unsure on the how or process, thus any process is good.  Everything in the question is what i need. Everything in the comments is a repeat of the question. So i am guessing you read neither

Comment: I read **everything**, up to and including your comment right above my last one where you were complaining that people downvoting or voting to close were not "at least put a comment", which is **exactly** why I "put a comment" when I downvoted. I'm not the one who isn't "reading neither". You asked me to tell you why I was downvoting if I did, and I did what you asked.

Comment: @KenWhite yes you did , but your reason was false there is no new info that i should add. I gave you +1 for at least commenting

Comment: New info from comments: To David "stored in a file type that user can't open (like ini)", and "preference is a non-readable text file" (whatever that means). To Nick: "The position, x,y,z of each TCube then the 3 integers value" (and more). All of that is new info not in your question (all you say is "save the array data...along with the integers"). Also not in your question is any effort to do anything yourself to save it, including at least an effort to save it to a text file.

Comment: to david it was a suggestion, which i said any way is fine,  the position i told nick cause thought maybe he did not know what the TCube property's where. I done effort in researching, posting here and looking up different ways, all of which have not helped enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best ways to save this type of data is by createing a record and saving the record. Then its not something human readable either.  Sof first create a new type

```
  TCubeSave = record
     number : integer;
     x : single;
     y : single;
     z : single;
     texture : string[20];
  end;
```

in this case we want to save the number in the array, along with the data x,y,z and texture?
If doing any string make sure its an array or you will get an error.

Next assign your variables and file and make it write ready.

```
var
 myfile : File of TCubeSave;
 cube : TcubeSave;
 i : integer;
begin
  assignfile(myfile, gamedir+'\maps\test.map');
  ReWrite(myfile);
  i:=0;
```

Now write each component of the array,
      while (i < totalblocks) do
       begin

Check if the component exsist, incase you have removed it or it was not created.

```
   if FindComponent('cubename'+inttostr(i)) <> nil then
       begin
```

Write the data to the file cube

```
        cube.number := i;
        cube.x := createcube[i].Position.X;
        cube.y := createcube[i].Position.Y;
        cube.z := createcube[i].Position.Z;
        cube.texture := createcube[i].Material.Texture.ToString;
        Write(myfile, cube);
       end;
      i := i+1;
   end;
```

close the file when done.

```
   CloseFile(myfile);
   showmessage('Map Saved');
end;
```

when ready to read in the file..

```
  // Reopen the file in read only mode
  FileMode := fmOpenRead;
  Reset(myFile);

  // Display the file contents
  while not Eof(myFile) do
  begin
    Read(myFile, cube);

      i:= cube.number;

      CreateCube[i]:=tcube.Create(self);
      createCube[i].Position.x := cube.x;
      createcube[i].position.y := cube.y;
       ect.....
  end;

  // Close the file
  CloseFile(myFile);
```

Comment: -1: IMHO save files are much better if they are human readable. It makes it easier to debug save/load problems, it's easier to maintain compatibility between different application versions, and so on...

Comment: @Glen If you don't want readers to edit the data then this solution is insufficient. The repetitive TCubeSave structures in the file are easily recognizable, anyone a bit computer savvy can experiment with a hex editor.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to save data out to a file. Normally I use [NativeXML](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html) to read and write XML documents. This probably isn't the best way but it works for me and has been suitable in my projects so far.

- It's human readable so you can see what's going on. Great for debugging when something isn't working right.
- It's structured. That helps when you need to save data for objects contained by other objects. For example, in your game world, there is a village, the village contains 10 buildings, building 1 contains 7 lamps, building 2 contains 3 swords, etc.
- It's a standard and commonly used format. Your game data files can be read and manipulated in other programs.
- The XML file can be encrypted as a way to prevent users from modifying the data.

Example of what the save code could look like:

```
procedure TMyGame.SaveToFile(const FileName: string);
var
  XML : TNativeXML;
  RootNode : TXmlNode;
  CubeNode : TXmlNode;
begin
  XML := TNativeXML.CreateName('root');
  try
    RootNode := XML.Root;

    for c1 := 0 to NumberOfCubes-1 do
    begin
      CubeNode := RootNode.NodeNew('Cube');

      CubeNode.NodeNew('XPos').ValueAsInteger := 10;
      CubeNode.NodeNew('YPos').ValueAsInteger := 2;
    end;

    XML.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    XML.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advocate for having human-readable data, such as with an XML or .ini file. If you need to block the user from being able to edit/modify the data, you can do that by "signing" the data and adding a validation key.  The key can be generated by your program by taking your sensitive data, appending something that only you know, and then generating an MD5 hash or encrypting it.  The MD5 result, or the first 100 bytes of the encrypted string, becomes your key which you would store in the .ini or whatever.
ex:

```
[MAPSTUFF]
SecretCoordinates=1,2,3,PIRATE TREASURE IS HERE
SignedKey=00042055215e2c6c0d751cb5b086e653
```

The SignedKey is actually an MD5 of the SecretCoordinates string + :XYZZY:
i.e. I ran this through MD5:
1,2,3,PIRATE TREASURE IS HERE:XYZZY:
and got:
00042055215e2c6c0d751cb5b086e653

So to check in the program, you read SecretCoordinates from the .ini file, add :ZYZZY: to it (in the program, so the user can't see (but if they have a debugger they still can)).  And see if you get the same MD5.  If it's a match, you're good. If it doesn't match, then the SecretCoordinates string has been tampered with, and you reject it.  Very simple.

Comment: +1 For the neccessary salting, otherwise this would be relatively easy to defeat ;-) The OP would have the option to ignore the MD5 during development for easy testing.